# Ng-Pattern performance issue with multiline regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

I have performance problems with ng-pattern on a textarea input.

I have a Regex expression to simply check if the code contains script, image or iframe tag. If I paste a script with multiple lines, after a certain size the entire input and page becomes unresponsive. At a certain point the entire browser tab dies.

Regex:

```
/^.*(<(img|iframe|script)( [^<]*)*>).*/m
```

Stackblitz for reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-btrpfi?file=home%2Fhome.html

Code I currently pass for testing:

```
<!-- Begin test script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = 123;
    var b = 24;
    var c = 22;
    var f = 56;
```

Steps to reproduce: Just add more lines and random content - doesn't really matter.

Any ideas how to get the multi line regex running? I'm aware in this simple case I can use a different approach to check for the tag inclusion compare to the multi-line regex approach, the original setup is a little more complex.

Comment: `( [^<]*)*` is a killing type of subpattern, do not use adjoining patterns that match the same text in a indefinitely quantified group.

Comment: Just simplify your regex and make it this /^.*(<(img|iframe|script)[^>]*?>).*/m

Comment: thanks for your response. if you want you add an answer, I'll gladly accept it.